# MySQL: Hilight few results like first in fetched list

Tags: php, mysql

I have database of all countries in the world sorted from A-Z and my client ask me to hilight few countries like a first in option list. How to do that?

My fields are `id`, `country_code`, `country_name`

Curret query:

```
 SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY country_name ASC
```

List is standard HTML select/option list and I need to display (by country_code) `UK`, `US`, `CA` like a first options in list and then other countries from A-Z.

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest transforming the sql result to an array on which you can do any kind of transformation.

Comment: Can you define *"highlight"* for us?

Comment: @ChaibiAlaanYeah in PHP is easy put all results in array and with `in_array()` separate what I need, save in new array and display but that is not optimized solution and unnecessary loop.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Generaly, I need highlight a particular country in the list as the first in line (first 4-5 options in list).

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić ah ok. I wasn't sure what you meant by that. I thought you may have meant something like a CSS highlight with yellow background lol - my bad ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ORDER BY` clause can contain any arbitrary expression - it need not be limited to column names. You can use an `IN ()` inside the `ORDER BY` to assign a low value (0) to those you want to highlight, and a higher value (1) to the rest. Follow that with your sort order `country_name ASC`, and both groups will be sorted alphabetically.

This works because a `0` is assigned to those in the `IN ()` list while `1` is assigned to the rest. The `0` always sort before the `1`.

```
SELECT *
FROM countries
ORDER BY
  CASE
    -- Assign lower sort values to the specified list
    WHEN country_code IN ('UK','US','CA') THEN 0
    -- And higher sort values to others
    ELSE 1
  END ASC,
  -- Sub-sort by name
  country_name ASC
```

Here is a brief demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d0cc/1

If you need to specify additional sorting on the highlighted set (such as to force `UK` to be first for example), that can be done by adding another column to the table to give a sort preference instead of relying on alphabetical sub-sorting. Assign lower values to the ones you want first, and the non-highlighted values may remain `NULL`.

```
code, name,          sort
UK,   United Kingdom, 1
CA,   Canada,         2
FR,   France          NULL
RU,   Russia          NULL
US,   United States   3
```

Then add that column `sort` into the `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN country_code IN ('UK','US','CA') THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END ASC,
  -- Sub-sort by the new "sort" column to force ordering
  sort ASC,
  -- Finally sort alphabetically for all those without 
  -- specific sort values
  country_name ASC
```

If you can live with alphabetic ordering amongst the highlighted rows though, you can avoid all this extra complexity.

Comment: WOOW this is powerfull. Thanks! That is solution what I looking for.

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić Glad I could help. Good luck to you.